# jsonload JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at

Tags: python, json

I've been webscraping some stuff over the past couple weeks and dumping it into a .txt file intermittently. My power goes out a lot so I have to restart it sometimes and it has to reread the .txt file and the most recent time I got the error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at
```

When doing

```
with open('user_scores.txt') as file:
     user_scores = (json.load(file))
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't tell me the line. The error output literally ends with the word "at" and then is just blank. I'm guessing that some bad characters got dumped in at some point and it can't read it anymore?

Edit:

When switching to json.load(file,strict=False)

I now get the error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at
```

Comment: Can you show your txt, pls?

Comment: @DaniloToro the text file is 500 mb and really long so there's not an easy way to show it that I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `strict` to `False`:

```
with open('user_scores.txt') as file:
     user_scores = json.load(file, strict=False)
```

---

> From the [documentation](https://fixes.co.za/python/json-loads-invalid-control-character/):
>
> If `strict` is `False` (`True` is the default), then control characters will be allowed inside strings. Control characters in this context are those with character codes in the 0–31 range, including `\t` (tab), `\n`, `\r` and `\0`.

Comment: When I try strict==False it still gives the "JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at" error

Comment: @user8151560 `strict==False` or `strict=False`?

Comment: sorry, when I tried strict=False it gave me a syntax error. I then had a brainfart and thought you meant strict==False which probably didn't do anything. Is my version of json out of date then?

Comment: user_scores = (json.load(file),strict=False)
                                                                      
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'm absolutely braindead, I forgot to change the parentheses!

Comment: I updated the main text. I'm getting the error "JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at" now

Comment: @user8151560 That means there is something wrong with the text file, not the code.

Comment: Is there a way I can print out the line it's failing on? Then I can just go in and manually delete it hopefully.

Comment: @user8151560 Is the file something you downloaded?

Comment: No, it's something I've been webscraping and then dumping. Like I said my power goes out a lot so maybe it went out while it was dumping the text file and it was left incomplete. I'm going to just try having it go through line by line and then dump whatever line is causing the error.

Comment: @user8151560 I think the easiest solution is to scrape again, as who knows *how* many lines could have errors.

Comment: it was just the last line that was messed up. I manually corrected it.

Comment: @user8151560 I'm glad!